# How do I get the 'kind' of portlet (group/context/type) from it's renderer in Plone

Tags: plone

Context:
I would like to build an URL to traverse to the current portlet to provide an external view rendering specific data.

Real use case:
I'm doing a video player which wait for an URL as parameters to get the video captions. Captions are stored in a schema.Text field. So the goal is to create a view to display theses data; something like:

```
  /++contextportlets++plone.rightcolumn/test-video/@@video_captions
```

So I'm in the python code renderer and I would like to build that URL from it. (self is renderer) I need:

- kind of portlet  in context, type, group
- manager name (self.manager.**name** do the job)
- portlet id (self.data.id do the job)

So the question is How do I get the kind of portlet from it's renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portlet category is only available from the portlet retriever. You can look it up by looping over the `getPortlets` method of the retriever. As the information that method returns deals with assignments, you'll need the portlet assignment (`.data` on a renderer), to pick out the correct entry:

```py
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter
from plone.portlets.interfaces import IPortletRetriever

# This assumes you have the portlet context and manager as attributes of self,
# like in the renderer:
retriever = getMultiAdapter((self.context, self.manager), IPortletRetriever)
for info in retriever.getPortlets():
     if info['assignment'] is self.data:
          return info['category']
```

Comment: Thanks it works with some adjustment (aquisition and the need of the path to the context. https://github.com/toutpt/collective.portlet.videoanysurfer/blob/master/collective/portlet/videoanysurfer/videoportlet.py#L107